# Turing Machines that interact with physics

Tags: computation, arithmetic

Fix a Turing-complete programming language P and character set. For sufficiently large 'n', an 'n' character program in P cannot decide the halting behavior of all programs with fewer than 2n characters (via a similar proof to the halting problem).

If I first feed the program a bunch of inputs that tell it how to decide all programs with fewer than 2n characters, then it can do so, no problem (as long as it's programmed to process this information). This isn't very interesting.

What if instead, I teleport the machine to a remote planet with no life and no ability to observe anything human or from humans. But it can observe its surroundings and interact with the universe. Is it conceivable that it can be designed in a way to eventually decide halting on programs in P with up to 2n characters?

The motivation is thinking about *we* gained this power.

Comment: This question is not easy to understand. Can you clarify what you are trying to determine?

Comment: Is the confusion that the program is accepting inputs in different stages? At the second stage, the program will be given strings of length 2n or less that correspond to a program, and it must decide correctly (in finite time) if those programs halt or not. At the first stage, the program will be given information it can use to aid it in the second stage.

Comment: The halting theorem only says that there are no algorithm that will compute if an arbitrary program and input will terminate or continue forever. When humans determine the halting of a program, they don't use an algorithm (i.e. a set of predefined instructions to be executed as is, without question), so the halting theorem is irrelevant. Also, one could argue it hasn't been demontrated that a human can find if _any_ program will halt, all the programmers in history taken together only have done such a determination for a very small subset of all possible programs.

Answer (score 1):

It's conceivable that some sort of hypercomputation is physically possible, and by "interacting with the universe" the machine could learn to decide the halting problem for any finite set of inputs, or for all inputs if it's allowed to "interact with the universe" after being fed the input.

> The motivation is thinking about we gained this power.

We don't have that power. For any reasonable notion of n for human beings, 2n is a very large number, and there are many shorter programs whose halting status we don't know, such as any program that contains a subprogram that searches for a counterexample to Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: [We don't even know BB(5)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver), let alone BB(6). Granted that is not exactly the same as halting, but close enough to show how difficult this proposition is. The reason we don't know it is that we don't know the halting status of several of these small turing machines.

Comment: I didn't mean for there to be too much focus on the last line, and I think the issue for BB of very small numbers has more to do with the sheer search size than our ability to decide individual programs of that size. From what I could find, the smallest known Turing machine whose behavior is genuinely open is 15 state. While I'm not sure how many states the most primitive form of life would take to simulate, I think it's reasonable to bet that whatever that number is, we aren't permanently bound to it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple-cum-trivial (counter-)example that I saw decades ago (so can't recall citation), originally in Fortran (I think), but let's rewrite its four lines in C.

Suppose you think you've written a C function

```
int ishalts(char *filename) { /*insert magic code here;*/ }
```

whose input is the name of a file containing some C program,
and whose output is 1 if the program in filename eventually halts,
or is 0 if it doesn't.

Okay, so now save the following program in file doIhalt.c, and try feeding it to ishalts(), as follows

```
int main ( ) {
  int ishalts();
  while ( ishalts("doIhalt.c") ) continue;
  exit(1); }
```

So our program paradoxically halts if ishalts() says it doesn't,
whereas it continues forever if ishalts() says it halts. So ishalts() is wrong, no matter what *magic code* it contains. Moreover, neither you nor I, as humans, can make that determination either,
at least I can't. Best I can say is it's paradoxical, but can't give any yes/no answer. Can you?

Comment: A program can't solve the general halting problem (although this specific proof doesn't quite work because doIhalt.c contains a function that must itself accept input and doesn't have halting/non-halting behavior on its own; it's easier to prove it non-constructively via diagonalization). This post is asking about solving the halting problem for a finite set of programs

Answer (score 0):

Computers don't make decisions, they execute code.

Code the program to flag processes with <=2n characters. Set a timer, or code it to randomly set its own timer. After that it's just a digital alarm clock that executes its process-stopping function on all indexes flagged with the <=2n flag until it runs out of thus-flagged indexes instead of executing its "beep beep beep" function. No exterior input is required.

If you want exterior input to make it "decide", give it a sensor and code it to execute the program after a particular measurement is made, either a certain time after the measurement which is based on certain measurements in certain sequence (like an alarm clock with the state of its buttons) or immediately (like a smoke alarm beeper with the state of its detector).

Comment: Are you familiar with the halting problem?